# DBManager in Android application

Tags: android, database

I am using a DBManager layer, it holds as private member all all the SQLiteOpenHelpers for the tables. The class is as followed

```
public class DBManager
{
    private static final String mTAG = "DBManager";
    Context                     mContext                = null;
    DB1         mDB1        = null;
    DB2         mDB2        = null;

    public DBManager( Context context )
    {
        mContext = context;

        mDB1    = new DB1( mContext );
        mDB2    = new DB2( mContext );
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable 
    {
        Close();

        super.finalize();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if( mDB1 != null ) mDB1.close();
        if( mDB2 != null ) mDB2.close();
    }

    .... Public API towards the DB1/DB2....
```

}

The question is like this:
Currently I am using it in each activity I need the DB as a private member.
Maybe better to use it as singleton? Can I? If do - which context to pass?
Or any other way to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do.  Keep one instance of SqliteOpenHelper per-database.  Do not keep more than one Helper for a single database.  This can cause issues with writes if more than one thread are trying to write at the same time.

Keep the Helper instance as a singleton across your application process.  Multiple Activity and Service clients can access it easily and you won't have write lock issues.

See here for details:

http://www.touchlab.co/blog/single-sqlite-connection/

It links to a few blog posts of mine about Sqlite and multiple connections.